# how to inner join between three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

```
uers(id,name,email,passowrd,contact,address,city)
items(id ,name,price)
users_item(id,user_id,item_id,status)
```

here `user_id` and `item_id` is foreign key.
how can i get resultant table with only `users_name,items_name,items_price,status` column?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to fetch those columns in my admin php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just join them....

```
SELECT *
FROM users U
LEFT JOIN user_items UI ON UI.USER_ID = U.ID
LEFT JOIN items I ON I.ID = UI.ITEM_ID
```